# Showing list empty message at the center of the screen in a FlatList using ListHeaderComponent

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using React-Native version 0.43.0 which does not support ListEmptyComponent of FlatList. Hence I am using ListHeaderComponent to render a view when the list is empty,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,FlatList } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listData: []
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          renderItem={() => null}
          data={this.state.listData}
          ListHeaderComponent={() => (!this.state.listData.length? 
            <Text style={styles.emptyMessageStyle}>The list is empty</Text>  
            : null)
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1
  },
  emptyMessageStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    //My current hack to center it vertically
    //Which does not work as expected
    marginTop: '50%', 
  }
});
```

[image]

> As you can see from the image the text is not centered vertically

Any idea how to center it vertically in a FlatList?

I have already tried applying justifyContent, alignItems etc but no use.

This is a link to the snack.expo - https://snack.expo.io/S16dDifZf

Comment: this work for me. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17944#issuecomment-382763099

Answer (score 67):

Hope this will help you

```
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    disableVirtualization={false}
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmptyContainer()}
      />
    }
  />
```

Place your UI in the renderEmptyContainer() method and boom, Empty container will show up whenever your list is empty

Comment: can u explain why we add    `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}` ?

Comment: @OliverD https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle  read this you will get to know :)

Comment: Thanks, I see, but what exactly I mean why we use flexGrow? Not Flex or something else

Answer (score 16):

They fixed `ListEmptyComponent` in this pr https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18206. But they will ship in 0.56.

**UPDATE:** Checkout the official doc [ListEmptyComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listemptycomponent)

Answer (score 7):

You can add a style to the FlatList.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1
  },
  listStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  emptyMessageStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    }

});

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList style={styles.listStyle}
          renderItem={() => null}
          data={this.state.listData}
          ListHeaderComponent={() => (!this.state.listData.length ? 
            <Text style={styles.emptyMessageStyle}>The list is empty</Text>  
            : null)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

This will center the items in the list, when the list is not empty. You may have to apply another style (when the list is not empty), if you don't prefer the non empty style.

[Link to snack.expo](https://snack.expo.io/By2wyaGWf)

Another option - without changing FlatList style - conditionally rendering FlatList based on `this.state.listData.length`

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          this.state.listData.length?

          (<FlatList 
            renderItem={() => null}
            data={this.state.listData}
          />) 
          :
          (
            <View style={styles.emptyListStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.emptyMessageStyle}>The list is empty</Text>  
            </View>
          )
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1
  },
  emptyListStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  emptyMessageStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    }

});
```

[This is the snack.expo](https://snack.expo.io/SkPFO6MbM)

Comment: I didn't know we could style FlatList, it's a good idea. But I don't want to introduce another check for FlatList style, I want to keep this rendering of list empty text separately as a component. Is there any possibility of doing that without changing FlatList style but only by changing that component style.

Comment: May be render the FlatList conditionally based on `this.state.listData.length`. I am editing my answer to add this approach.

Comment: But I want the functionality pull to refresh so only I going inside FlatList.

Comment: Then I can think only about conditionally setting the style for FlatList. `<FlatList style={this.state.listData.length? {} : styles.emptyListStyle}` 
 - https://snack.expo.io/ByZ1ZCGZf

Answer (score 7):

You must combine props `ListEmptyComponent` with `contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}` flex:1 will set the maximal height in the container and will allow you to center vertically. ie:

```
<FlatList 
    ...
    contentContainerStyle={customers.length === 0 && styles.centerEmptySet}
    ListEmptyComponent={<EmptySetCustomer />}
/>
```

Note that you must set a condition to remove flex:1 when list is not empty. To allow scroller.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 7):

This resolve for me.

```
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"}}
    disableVirtualization={false}
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    ListEmptyComponent={this.renderEmptyContainer()}
      />
    }
  />
```

Comment: Wanted to point out that this solution, while does work on the empty component, also affects the actual list content

Comment: `disableVirtualization` is now deprecated

Answer (score 3):

As a temporary workaround you can conditionally set a style to the contentContainer to center only the empty set like this

```
<FlatList 
    contentContainerStyle={customers.length === 0 && styles.centerEmptySet}
    data={customers}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        /// Your item here
    )}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
        return String(index);
    }}
    ListEmptyComponent={<EmptySetCustomer />}
/>
```

And styles like this

```
centerEmptySet: { justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100%' }
```

Then in 2-3 weeks we can update to 0.56 and remove the workaround

Answer (score 3):

```js
<FlatList
keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  data={flatListItems}
    ListEmptyComponent={<View style= {styles.EmptytextHeader}><Text style={styles.EmptyMassage}>No data found</Text></View>}
             renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        return <View><Text>add Your Data</Text></View>

                        />
                    }}
                />
                
                
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    EmptytextHeader: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    EmptyMassage: {
       color:'red',
        fontWeight: '700',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontStyle: 'normal',
    },
    });
```

**its working**